# Sorting organic keywords by total conversions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

If you go to Acquisition > Keywords > Organic in Google Analytics, you can see a list of keywords that people searched for when search engines like Google sent them to your website. Now if you have conversions set up, you can also sort this list by conversion ratio.

**How would you go about sorting this list by not the conversion ratio, but total conversions instead?**

For example, if Google sent you 100 people that searched for "cat" and 5 people that searched for "dog". Suppose 5 of the cat people converted and 1 of the dog people converted. Sorting by conversion ratio you would get "dog" at 20% as the first result and "cat" at 5% in second place. I would like to see "cat" first at 5 conversions and "dog" second at 1 conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click the "Goal Completions" header (2nd from the right):

[image]

Comment: To make this appear, first I needed to click a drop-down menu that has "eCommerce" selected to select "All Goals" instead. After that the "Goal Completions" header appeared. Thank you!

Comment: The screenshot is from the "Summary"-tab, but it should also work in the goal tabs and the "E-commerce"-tab. Google may not have rolled "Summary" out to everyone yet.